# Why doesn't Django serialize FileField to the file url when using AWS S3

Tags: django, serialization, amazon-s3

Scenario: I'm using Amazon S3 as default storage using S3 Boto and all files would be going to **'media'** folder in my bucket.

Question: When I am serializing the model containing my FileField to json using `serializers.serialize`, all I get in the json is **'media/abc.png'** or something of that sort. Is there a way to automatically get the file url in json instead of the relative path or should I manually append the url into the json response every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django operates with [File objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/file/), Storages and FileField. Filefield saves some kind of storage identifier for the file. This identifier helps storage to find the right location of the file. By default serializer gets only that identifier. And that identifier is string representation of django file object.

If you want to return url, you need to override serializer method:

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.db import models

JSONSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")

class JSONWithURLSerializer(JSONSerializer):

    def handle_field(self, obj, field):
        value = field.value_from_object(obj)
        if isinstance(field, models.FileField) and hasattr('url', value):
            self._current[field.name] = value.url
        else:
            return super(JSONWithURLSerializer, self).handle_field(obj, field)

serializer = JSONWithURLSerializer()
serializer.serialize(queryset)
data = serializer.getvalue()
```

Comment: I was already thinking on the lines of this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Is there a reason django doesn't support this out of the box ? I feel that any file should automatically point to the MEDIA_ROOT+Rel.PATH by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup and the following worked for me -

1. Remove/Comment out MEDIA_ROOT in (your_project)/settings.py
2. 

If you're using @api_view, pass the context and pass the request object.

```
serializer = ProductSerializer(customer, context={"request": request})
```

Or if you're using ViewSet -

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

def get_serializer_context(self):
    return {'request': self.request}
```

Your serializer -

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'     #<--passing all values
```