# How to convert Django model that has FileField into JSON

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I tried to get the last inserted data from the following method

```
latest = AudioContentModel.objects.latest('id').id
object = model_to_dict(AudioContentModel.objects.get(pk=latest))
```

but I get the following error

```
TypeError: Object of type 'FieldFile' is not JSON serializable
```

How can I get the data from the table that was last inserted?

This is my model.py

```
class AudioContentModel(models.Model):
        background_music = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
        tts = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
        final_audio = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
        created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is my view.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            audiouploadform = AudioUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if audiouploadform.is_valid():
                audiouploadform.save()
                latest = AudioContentModel.objects.latest('id').id
                print('Need to get the all the data from the latest and resturn as a JsonResponse')
            data{
              'background_music':
              'tts':
              'id':
            }
                return JsonResponse({'error': False, 'data': data})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'error': True, 'errors': audiouploadform.errors})
        else:
            error = {
                'message': 'Error! Must be an Ajax call'
            }
            return JsonResponse(error, content_type="application/json")
    else:
        audiouploadform = AudioUploadForm()
        all_audio_files = AudioContentModel.objects.all()
        data = {
            'audio_file_list': all_audio_files,
            'audiouploadform': audiouploadform,
        }
    return render(request, template_name='index.html', context=data)
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789597/why-doesnt-django-serialize-filefield-to-the-file-url-when-using-aws-s3

Comment: You should be using serializers. If you're doing this a lot, consider Django REST Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

```
        latest = AudioContentModel.objects.latest('id').id
        print(latest)
        instance = AudioContentModel.objects.get(pk=latest)
        data = {
            'id': instance.id,
            'background_music': instance.background_music.url,
            'tts': instance.tts.url,
            'created':instance.created,
        }
```